# Delete the last two characters of the String

Tags: java, string, substring

How can I delete the last two characters `05` of the simple string?

**Simple:**

```
"apple car 05"
```

**Code**

```
String[] lineSplitted = line.split(":");
String stopName = lineSplitted[0];
String stop =   stopName.substring(0, stopName.length() - 1);
String stopEnd = stopName.substring(0, stop.length() - 1);
```

orginal line before splitting ":"

```
apple car 04:48 05:18 05:46 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46 16:46 17:16 17:46 18:16 18:46 19:16
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Anything in the javadoc?

Comment: I have tried the code above but I have the feeling it is the wrong way.

Comment: @FastSnail: I am splitting to get the words at the begging of the line.

Comment: One simple solution is using two `pop_back()`s.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Subtract `-2` or `-3` basis of removing last space also.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "apple car 05";
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length() - 2));
    }
```

**Output**

```
apple car
```

Comment: Why does Java doesn't want to clean this functionality up? String parsing is extensively used in Orgs of every scale. In Python its as simple as `s[:-2]`. That's it.

Comment: @Sankalp, Python is easier to learn, but it is slow and sometimes unpredictable. In Java you type more code, but you get fast and reliable result.

Answer (score 35):

Use [String.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```
str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);
```

The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index (endIndex - 1)

Comment: It may not work if we increase the string size. So I think it's better to remove from the last what is seen in other answers.

Comment: @masud.m updated the answer as you suggested.

Comment: should be `str.length - 3`

Answer (score 5):

You may use the following method to remove last `n` character -

```
public String removeLast(String s, int n) {
    if (null != s && !s.isEmpty()) {
        s = s.substring(0, s.length()-n);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring` function:

```
s.substring(0,s.length() - 2));
```

With the first `0`, you say to `substring` that it has to start in the first character of your string and with the `s.length() - 2`  that it has to finish 2 characters before the String ends.

For more information about `substring` function you can see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

It was almost correct just change your  last line like:

```
String stopEnd = stop.substring(0, stop.length() - 1); //replace stopName with stop.
```

**OR**

you can replace your last two lines;

```
String stopEnd =   stopName.substring(0, stopName.length() - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the following code with exception handling. Here you have a method `removeLast(String s, int n)` (it is actually an modified version of **masud.m**'s answer). You have to provide the `String` s and how many `char`  you want to remove from the last to this `removeLast(String s, int n)` function. If the number of `char`s have to remove from the last is greater than the given `String` length then it throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundException` with a custom message -

```
public String removeLast(String s, int n) throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException{

        int strLength = s.length();

        if(n>strLength){
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("Number of character to remove from end is greater than the length of the string");
        }

        else if(null!=s && !s.isEmpty()){

            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-n);
        }

        return s;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use some sort of `regex`:

for example:

```
    String s = "apple car 04:48 05:18 05:46 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46 16:46 17:16 17:46 18:16 18:46 19:16";
    String results=  s.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").replaceAll(" :", ""); //first removing all the numbers then remove space followed by :
    System.out.println(results); // output 9
    System.out.println(results.length());// output "apple car"
```